# Wasm instruction ambiguity for sign-extension?

Tags: webassembly, instructions, sign-extension

Are there any differences with respect to the effect
of `i64.extend32_s` and `i64.extend_i32_s` or are they just duplicates?

I'm trying to implement a toy compiler/interpreter lib for wasm, and the specification/documentation are not clear about it, but it is kinda important for correctness.

Comment: Is `i64extend_i32_s` (no dot) supposed to be `i64.extend32_s`?  An answer only talks about the name with a dot.  (But the bottom of the answer says (ChatGPT), and the writing style looks like some or all of it could have been generated by ChatGPT, which is banned because it tends to make stuff up, so I wouldn't fully trust it.)

Comment: oh can't tell if that is true, but yes ChatGPT are good at making false claims and statements.
Using the web as training data are just as faulty as using prior convictions in US to train a AI to determine if a suspect is guilty (as proven).

Answer (score 2):

I have just asked the formal working group for WASM.

Answer:

```
i64.extend32_s has type signature i64 -> i64

i64.extend_i32_s had type signature i32 -> i64
```

hence the difference is in input